# Access data in a UDF (User Defined Function) in DocumentDB

Tags: user-defined-functions, azure-cosmosdb, udf

Is there a way, to read and process data (e.g. lookup) in a UDF?

I've seen only samples for StoredProcedures. 
In a UDF, I get an error with the getContext() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can only operate on what is passed in. If you can embed the lookup in the UDF code that is a possibility. If you need to get the lookup data from the collection, then a stored procedure is your best option.

Comment: But can I include a stored proc in a Where clause of a SQL statement?

Comment: No, but you can include an SQL statement in a stored proc.